# URL check with JS

Tags: javascript

I have two scripts, first of them clicks on the button and after that browser opens a new window, where i should click on the other button by the second script, is it possible to run them both at the same time, I mean like unite those scripts together?

```
function run() {
var confirmBtn = document.querySelector(".selector,anotherSelector ");
}
```

after this new window appears and here`s the second part of my script

```
var rooms = document.querySelectorAll(" .btn-a-offers");
console.log(rooms);
for (var room = 0; room < rooms.length; room++) {
    rooms[room].click();
}
var prices = document.querySelectorAll(" .li-right-side>strong");
console.log(prices);
for (var price = 0; price < price.length; price++) {

}
var prices = [];
document.querySelectorAll(".new-pa-hotelsoffers .li-right-side > strong").forEach(function(price) {
    prices.push(parseFloat(price.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")))
})
console.log(
    Math.min(...prices).toFixed(2)
)
```

My English is not that good so I want to be sure that I explained everything right, second script must be executed in the new window, that opens after first script

Comment: So, to clarify, the process is `click button` -> `change location` -> `script clicks on another button automatically`?

Comment: It is probably possible, yes. If you'd like help doing that, please provide a [mcve] of the scripts involved.

Comment: Oliver, yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: Just to start, you won't be able to run a single script across multiple documents

Comment: Does the second script always need to run, or _only_ run when the first button is pressed?

Comment: You could include the other function in a `document.ready` function on the redirected location. That will make the other script execute once that page has been loaded. However, if you use that page for multiple purposes, and only want the other function called upon the act of the first function, then that would not be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the logical dependancy of your application and the use of the functions, you could execute the second function in a `document.ready` function on the second page.

Example:

```
<script>
//jQuery
$( document ).ready(function() {
    secondFunction();
});

//Pure JS
function r(f){/in/.test(document.readyState)?setTimeout('r('+f+')',9):f()}

r(function() {
    secondFunction();
});
</script>
```

However, if the page is to act independantly, and the *second* function is only to respond upon the execution of the *first* function, then that solution would not be the one you are looking for.

In the case where the function has to act entirely dependant on the use of the *first* function you could parse a value in the URL (better known as a `GET` variable) and check if that value is set.

Example:

```
<script>
functionOne() {
    window.location.href = '/your_page.php?click=1';
}
</script>
```

Then on your second page you need to retrieve the `GET` variable.

```
<?php
$clicked = $_GET['click'];
?>
```

You can then perform a check to see if the variable has been set and fire your function upon that logic.

```
<?php
if($clicked != "") {
    echo '
    <script>
    functionTwo();
    </script>';
}
?>
```

Another way of doing it could be by the use of `AJAX` and have the other function execute in the AJAX' *success* function. That way you can eliminate the use of the `GET` variable, which is visible in the URL.

Example:

```
<script>
functionOne() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST", //or GET
        url : "/your_page.php",
        data : {
            //parse your POST variable data if any
            // variable : value,
            // anotherVairable : anotherValue
            // [....]
        },
        success: function (html) {
            //Success handling
            secondFunction();
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

Note that the AJAX used in the example is jQuery AJAX, so if you want to use some AJAX logic involving this structure, you'll need to include a jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass some parameter in the URL query like this:

```
// first-script.js
openNewWindow('http://example.com?run-second-script=1') // openNewWindow is fake function, just for demo

// second-script.js
if (window.location.search.includes('run-second-script=1')) { ... your code here ...}
```